# How Could I compare two fields in an strapi entity

Tags: strapi

For example, I have an entity with two fields:
user (following, followers)

I want to search on users and find all users that following is more than followers. I use this SQL query:

```
select * from user where following > followers
```

How could I do this search in Strapi?

Comment: Hello 
Am facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using knext.js (that strapi use this library to run queries) and ref function in strapi like this:

```
var res = 
await strapi.db.connection.table("user").select().where("following", ">", strapi.db.connection.ref("followers"));
```

You can find more information about this library in this page:
https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#where

Answer (score 1):

I had to use raw query in order to achieve that

```
  let {rows} = await strapi.db.connection.raw(
`select * from user where following > followers`);
```